# How can I configure IIS on Azure to stream chunked data from a Node.js app?

Tags: iis, http, azure, node.js, http-streaming

I have a Node.js app that uses `Transfer-Encoding: Chunked` to stream data over HTTP continuously until the client disconnects. When running a local instance of Node, it works fine, but when deployed to an Azure App Service (which runs Node apps through [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode)), client connections hang without ever receiving data.

Logging indicates that the Node app is processing requests and streaming data correctly, but for some reason that data is not reaching the client.

Here's a simplified example of the way I'm streaming data from Node:

```
var server = http.createServer();
server.on('request', function(request, response) {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        response.write("some data\r\n");
    }, 1000);
    request.on('close', function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
});
server.listen(config.port);
```

In my `iisnode.yml` config file I have set `flushResponse: true` to prevent iisnode from buffering response chunks.

My *guess* is that IIS is trying to buffer the entire response before sending it, but I don't know how to disable this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. Set `flushResponse` to true in `web.config` - see https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full listing of options.

So, you'd have the line in `web.config`:

```
<iisnode flushResponse="true"/>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thank you for sharing! I ran into the same issue with my app working locally but not on Azure Web Apps, should have suspected IIS sooner.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're running IIS on your VM (and don't make use of Azure App Service).
 This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568696/how-to-turn-off-buffering-in-iis-for-mvc-4-web-api-application) gives some directions how to disable IIS response buffering (aka **AspBufferingOn**).

Basically you need to install **ASP feature** and the option will be displayed in IIS Manager (see details [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/asp/limits)).

Comment: This is an App Service, so unfortunately I don't have that option.

Comment: Have you check [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/925764)? `You can disable buffering on the Web server, at the application level, or at the page level. When you disable buffering, the Web server uses HTTP chunked-transfer encoding to send the response to the Web client.` Web server level on Azure App Service doesn't seem possible, at the application level you need to modify a metabase property and that's also not possible but you may have a chance with the page level (it gives a solution with ASP), how would that translate in Node? If it doesn't work I'd switch to a Web role.

Answer (score 0):

```
on('request', function(request, response) {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        response.write("some data\r\n");
    }, 1000);
    request.on('close', function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
```

Comment: and your point is?